# run a javascript function before other function

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code:

```
var is_recorded_book; 
function callback(data){

  is_recorded_book = data.result
  alert(is_recorded_book)

}

function check_book(){
  Dajaxice.darkoob.migration.is_book(callback, {'book_title': $('#id_book_title').val() })
  alert ("check book" +is_recorded_book);
  if (is_recorded_book){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

and a have a form like this:

```
        <form action="..." method='...' onsubmit='return check_book()'>
...
          <input type='submit' />
```

but my output is:
alert ("check book" +is_recorded_book);
alert (is_recorded_book)

but i want run `alert(is_recorded_book)` at first.

i edit my check_book function to:

```
function check_book(){
    Dajaxice.darkoob.migration.is_book(function(data){
    callback(data);
    alert('dfsdf')
    if (is_recorded_book){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }, {'book_title': $('#id_book_title').val() })
}
```

but alert('dfsdf') not work.

Comment: The way your code is structured, there is no way you will be able to do the asynchronous call and be able to cancel the form submission. You will have to change the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the alert inside the callback:

```
Dajaxice.darkoob.migration.is_book(function (data) {
    callback(data);
    alert("check book" +is_recorded_book);
}, {'book_title': $('#id_book_title').val() });
```

Comment: @28 Try using console.log() instead of alert because alert is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your `check_book` works:

1. you make an **asynchronous** http request: this means that the request is sent and waits for the server to respond
2. meanwhile the `alert check_book` is displayed and the function returns false, since `isRecorder_book` is still undefined
3. after some time, when the server responds, the `callback` runs and sets the `is_recorder_book` (too late)

There are some workarounds

1. either use **synchronous** http request (set the third parameter to `false` in [open](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open%28%29-method) method).
2. Or submit the form by the callback after setting the `is_recorder_book`

*The code for the second option:*

```
var is_recorded_book = false; 
function callback(data) {
  is_recorded_book = data.result;
  alert(is_recorded_book);
  alert("check book" +is_recorded_book);
  document.getElementById("yourform").submit();
}

function check_book(){
  Dajaxice.darkoob.migration.is_book(
    callback, {'book_title': $('#id_book_title').val() }
  );
}

<form id="yourform" onsubmit="check_book(); return is_recorder_book;">
```